# Jquery/Ajax to update a DIV [ASP.NET MVC 4.0]

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following problem:

I have to update simply a DIV using a Jquery/Action section in my view.

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Prova() {
  return PartialView("Prova")
}
```

This is my view of the Controller (index.cshtml)

```
<script src="~/Models/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js type="text/javascript"></script>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Home","Prova",new AjaxOptions() {
    HttpMethod="GET",
    UpdateTargetId="divProva",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace
})

<div Id="divProva"></div>
```

This is my partial view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title="Prova";
}
```

When I click on the "Prova" link, it opens a new page with the partial view content. It doesn't update the div. What is my mistake?

Comment: when I have had a partial redirect instead of updating the view it was because I was missing a reference to unobtrusive ajax on the form.  Try adding that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which uses normal ActionLink helper method and your own javascript to handle the click event of the anchor tag to load the ajax content to the div.

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyLinkName","Prova","Home",null,new {@class="ajaxLink"})
```

and some javascript which listens to the click event on a tags with the css class we specified for our link(`ajaxLink`) and reload the content using jQuery `load` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  $("a.ajaxLink").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default click behavior

    $("#divProva").load($(this).attr("href"));

  });

});
```